# Looking for OSS for OSI Layer 2 Traffic Generator

Tags: c++, c, networking, osi

I am looking for layer 2 traffic generator [open source].

Some OSS using winpcap or libpcap.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [Scapy](http://secdev.org/projects/scapy)
- [bittwist](http://bittwist.sourceforge.net)
- any from perl's Net::Pcap, python's or ruby's pcap interface...

Comment: Although, if you're not looking for something you can program yourself, you may be at the wrong place :-)

Comment: thanks mat, although i am coding that only using WinPcap. But i was stuck with BER Pattern. If you have any link/pdf of of raw packet building and generating @ 1 gig speed packets let me know would be glad if you could do so ;)